# How can I find files that are not modified in the last five months?

Tags: linux, date-modified

At our university we have the policy that on certain disks' data is deleted if it is not modified for six months. Now I would like to list all files that have not been modified in the last five months.

How can I do this? I have access to all basic Linux tools, like [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find), etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is

```
find directory -mtime +150
```

for the files *not* modified in this period (`-150` will list the *modified* files).

Comment: That will list files that have been modified more than 150 days ago.

Comment: Yes... and they are the the same as the files not modified in the 150 last days (or 5 months) of course: this command lists all the files excepting the files modified in the last 5 months... so the others (listed) are the not modified in this time.

Comment: It lists directories as well. is it possible to list only files

Comment: Use `-type f`` for only files

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be more precise regarding leap years and particular month lengths, you can do this:

```
find /dir/to/start/from -type f -mtime +$(((10#$(date +%s) - 10#$(date -d "now - 5 months" +"%s")) / (24*60*60)))
```

Here's how the number of days would vary if the above were run on the first day of each month in 2010:

```
1 153
2 153
3 151
4 151
5 150
6 150
7 149
8 152
9 153
10 153
11 153
12 153
```

As you can see "150" is only an approximation. However, for most purposes approximations (such as `24*60*60` as a matter of fact) are good enough.